Groups without infinitely divisible elements
Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group. Call an element $g \in G$ infinitely divisible if there exist infinitely many positive integers $N$ such that $h^N = g$ for some $h \in G$.
Question: is there an easy way to describe (or even characterize) large classes of groups without nontrivial infinitely divisible elements ?
Example given: finitely generated abelian groups have this property, but what happens when we drop the "abelian condition," and add "torsion-free" (example given) ?

It is clear that your property implies torsion-free, so there's no point in "dropping the torsion-free condition". Or alternatively, ask about groups in which every element of infinite order is not infinitely divisible.

Two large classes of such groups (a) torsion-free groups with Property PW (i.e., acting properly on CAT(0) cube complexes) (b) torsion-free subgroups of the wobbling group of $\mathbf{Z}$ (the groups of permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$ that are at finite distance to identity. [In both cases if we drop "torsion-free" we still get that elements of infinite order are not infinitely divisible.]

All torsion-free hyperbolic groups. But I am not sure what would count as a satisfactory answer to such an open-ended question.
